# Interfacing wxPython with Octave to launch .m Files

Tags: wxpython, octave

Looking into integrating wxPython GUI with .m functions
Do i need Octave to do that? and if so, how do I interface wxPython with octave and access .m files residing on my desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Octave sounds like a programming language in its own right. If you want to open a file with another program, then you normally want to look at Python's subprocess module. You can read about it here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

It is very easy to put a subprocess call inside an event handler in wxPython. You just bind a button to an event (such as wx.EVT_BUTTON) and then you call subprocess in the handler. If the .m file is for MATLAB, then you can probably call that with subprocess too. An alternative to MATLAB are the NumPy and SciPy packages, but I don't think you can run a MATLAB file with them. See the following article for more information: https://sites.google.com/site/pythonforscientists/python-vs-matlab